# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, localhost

I'm new to Linux. I'm trying to run a project on localhost. It has worked but now I  got this error:

`SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I tried to change password in this way:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5`

but still no result. 
How to fix that?

Comment: I entered password and change it, after that restart mysql and still get this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the password for `root@localhost` blank to other.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('root');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u root -p
```

It will then prompt for your password. If this fails, then definitely the username or password is incorrect.

Comment: then you have issue with password

Comment: After I run this and entered password I got: Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 50... I think it is ok, but I can't find problem

Comment: Yes, I log in phpmyadmin with these username and pawword.

Comment: Oh sorry for my question, I've set another password in my project database file :D